# IPTables forwarding no more connection

Tags: iptables, forwarding

I have a VPS for protect windows server from DDOS so I have forwarding connection.

The forward works great but I can't access to the internet with the VPS. Ping doesn't works and I can't update or install apt.

This is my Iptables file:

```
#RESET
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -X

echo -n '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo -n '0' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route
echo -n '0' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects
echo -n '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
echo -n '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses


/sbin/iptables -P INPUT DROP
/sbin/iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

#DROP SCAN
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,URG,PSH FIN,URG,PSH -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP

#DROP BROADCAST
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP

#PORT OUVERT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

#RDP Rules
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination XX.XX.XX.XX:3389

#MASQUER L'IP DES FORWARD
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

XX.XX.XX.XX is for the example.

Why I can't access to the internet with this iptables active ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your INPUT chain drops dynamically opened ports. I think you should accept the packages related to your OUTPUT traffic. Add this line before the DROP rules:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html